# How to return only the first row containing the value you are searching for in a query?

Tags: google-sheets

```
=QUERY('F/O DEFVSREC'!$1:$1000, "select C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V where B='"&A35&"'label C'', D'', E'', F'', G'', H'', I'', J'', K'', L'', M'', N'', O'', P'', Q'', R'', S'', T'', U'', V''")
```

There is the formula I am currently using.  I have two rows on my F/O DEFvsREC sheet that contains the value i'm looking for.  I need to only return the first row containing that value.  The row number is 19.

I apologize if i'm asking really simple questions.  I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To return only one row, use [`limit 1`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#limit) in the query; this clause appears before `label`:

```
select C, D, ... where B='"&A35&"' limit 1 label C'', D''...
```

The default order of the rows returned by `query` is the order in which they appear in the sheet, so this will result in the first row being returned.

---

**Alternative solution**: use [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) instead. The formula will be a lot shorter:

```
=array_constrain(filter(C:V, B:B = A35), 1, 1e7)
```

The filter keeps selects columns C through V only from the rows with B equal to the content of A35. Then, `array_constrain` forces the output to have no more than 1 row  and 1e7 (=10000000) columns. (The absurdly large number of columns is just to indicate we don't impose a limit on columns.)

Comment: I'm inputting data from a separate sheet.  So how would I add the sheet key.  "F/O DEFVSREC" into this array_constrain filter formula to get it working correctly?

Comment: Put `'F/O DEFVSREC'!C:V` instead of `C:V`, and similarly for `B:B`. This is just how cell references are made, it doesn't depend on what command you use.